# Session deleted because of page crash

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**What happened?**
While running a selenium script in the keda after some point of time script is break due to this error:
`from the website i am getting this error: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash from unknown error: cannot determine loading status from tab crashed`

**How can we reproduce the issue?**

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_service = ChromeService(
  executable_path='CHROME_EXECUTABLE_PATH'
)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=options)
driver.get('https://us04web.zoom.us/j/7791292XXXX')
join() # call join function
mute() # mute mic
```

**Relevant log output**
`from the website i am getting this error: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash from unknown error: cannot determine loading status from tab crashed`

**Operating System**
Linux OS

**Selenium version**
selenium=4.17.0

**Browser(s) and version(s)**
Chrome 121

**browser driver(s) and version(s)**
121

I also checked the CPU usage; it is within acceptable levels and not exhausted.